# OpenLayers 'wrapX' not working on ol.source.XYZ() source

Tags: openlayers, xyz

I recently posted a [question about a WMTS layer not appearing in my OpenLayers map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404917/openlayers-wmts-function-no-longer-working-no-error-messages), and the resolution turned out to be that I needed to add the 'wrapX' option (or otherwise to pan all the way around the world the other way - either case would result in the layer appearing OK).

I am now experiencing a similar problem with an XYZ layer.  My extent, in the example below starts off in Baltimore, but panned right around the world once (which the users are entitled to do).  The XYZ layer doesn't appear.  If I pan all the way around the world westwards, then the layer does appear.

I do have `wrapX` enabled for this layer though!

Why is the wrapX option not working here?  What have I done wrong?

Full JS code Using OpenLayers 6.5.1 is below:

```
function newLayerTileGrid(urlTemplate, tileGridJSON, projCode, projString) {
    var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid( JSON.parse(
                                                        '{"tileSizes":[[256,256],[256,256],[256,256],[256,256],[256,256],[256,256],[256,256]],"origins":[[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002],[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002],[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002],[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002],[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002],[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002],[-8553609.2125000004,4783123.4818000002]],"extent":[-8553609.2125000004,4754994.6555000003,-8509581.4857999999,4783123.4818000002],"minZoom":0,"maxZoom":6,"resolutions":[305.74810208333656,152.87405104166828,76.43702552083414,38.21851276041707,19.109256380208535,9.5546281901042676,4.7773140950521338]}'
                                                        ) );
    var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
        url:'file:///Users/my_name/blah/blah/blah/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        tileGrid: tileGrid,
        wrapX: true,
    });
    
    return new ol.layer.Tile({ source: source, extent: tileGrid.getExtent() });
}

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View(),
});

map.getView().fit([31537494, 4745063, 31555757, 4784609], map.getSize(), {constrainResolution: false});

layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() });
map.addLayer(layer);

layer = newLayerTileGrid();
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: You do not need to set layer extent if it is the same as the tilegrid extent.  Layer extents do not wrap.

Comment: I use a layer extent for some of the data sets as they are created as a user-defined area of a larger (sometimes global) data set.  All tiles that intersect the area are included but this results in some tiles that are partially outside of the defined area.  So without a layer extent, not only does it display a different (superset) area than was defined, but the area is different at each zoom level (which is quite jarring).  I will have to consider either ditching layer extents and tolerating the incorrect and variable area, OR turning off wrapX altogether for the entire map and all layers.

Comment: @Mike - thanks for this.  Makes sense.  As explained in my comment above, I have a requirement for layer extents for some of these data sets.   Are you aware of any way to restrict display of the dataset to a particular extent that is also compatible with wrapX?

Comment: It could be done with ol.source.Raster.  Create a tile grid covering only the extent to be displayed.  Combine with the source you want to display, using the rgb from your source but combining the with opacity of the restricted source. https://codesandbox.io/s/layer-extent-wrapped-kvwoi

Comment: Nice work.  That looks like a novel solution.  I'm not sure if I want to pursue it that far or not, but it's nice to know that the option is there.  (The instances where this is actually going to cause problems for real users are going to be very rare, I think.)